# CSS - IE7 weirdness - When I set the opacity of an element, I lose the margin of a sibling element

Tags: css, internet-explorer-7

When I set the opacity of an element ( `filter:alpha(opacity=50);` ) then the margin of the element to the right of it goes to 0, and butts right up against the element for some reason.

This doesn't happen when setting opacity on firefox or chrome, but does happen on IE7.

Anyone know how to fix this?

Comment: In other words, this doesn't happen when you leave jQuery out the context and set the (appropriate) CSS manually in a style(sheet)?

Comment: @balus Just checked, it also happens without using javascript and just setting `filter:alpha(opacity50);` in my stylesheet

Comment: Sorry, can't reproduce. There is something more at matter. Please post an copy'n'paste'n'runnable [SSCCE](http://sscce.org) in flavor of `<!doctype html><html>...</html>` with the minimum required content to reproduce the same problem.

Comment: @balus that page didn't load for me, but i found out when the containing div has position:relative, the problem occurs, but with position:static, the problem doesn't happen.

Comment: Ah that sounds like another [hasLayout](http://www.satzansatz.de/cssd/onhavinglayout.html) issue again. Try giving `.elem` a `zoom: 1`. It should give the element "layout" in IE6/7. Yes, I know that I should probably post this as an answer, but it's as far only guessing because the lack of a workable SSCCE and the many bugs/oddities IE6/7 is rich of.

Comment: I'll post this as an answer then.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As per the comments:

> Ah, that sounds like another [hasLayout](http://www.satzansatz.de/cssd/onhavinglayout.html) issue again. Try giving `.elem` a `zoom: 1`. It should give the element "layout" in IE6/7.